# where can i get if there is any free platform or buy a shopping cart for a php platform

Tags: php

I have made a site and i have some products in it,the site is made in php and I want to integrate a shoping card as well on it.

Would you please suggest me any platform as open source or which one is the best you think to buy.

By saying the best i mean also, easy to install and integrate it.

One more question, if i have the shoping cart, should I also consult with any of the banks, or the script it does the job itself by giving my Credit card's details, i mean for the transaction of the moneys.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use zend cart (open source) and it works great out of the box, as well as fairly easy to make modifications to. They also have a great community
It supports paypal, offline credit card processing, etc

There is also osCommerce, but I have never used it.